# Method from OnActivityResult Fragment executed, but nothing happend in View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-camera, imagepicker

can you help me., ?
I am new in develop Android use kotlin, and still learning.,

this my code on **Fragment**.,

```
......
  private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {

        Dexter.withActivity(requireActivity())
            .withPermissions(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            )
            .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                    // Here after all the permission are granted launch the CAMERA to capture an image.
                    if (report!!.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                        intent.putExtra("Document", 2)
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA)
                    }
                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                    token: PermissionToken?,
                ) {
                    showRationalDialogForPermissions()
                }
            }).onSameThread()
            .check()
    }

    private fun choosePhotoFromGallery() {
        Dexter.withActivity(activity)
            .withPermissions(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
            .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {

                    // Here after all the permission are granted launch the gallery to select and image.
                    if (report!!.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {

                        val galleryIntent = Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        )
                     galleryIntent.putExtra("Document", 2)
                     startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
                    }
                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                    token: PermissionToken?,
                ) {
                    showRationalDialogForPermissions()
                }
            }).onSameThread()
            .check()
    }
```

and this **onActivityResult** from parent **Activity** for **Fragment**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        for (fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
```

And this **OnActivityResult** from **Fragment**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                val contentURI = data.data
                try {
                    // Here this is used to get an bitmap from URI
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    val selectedImageBitmap =
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireActivity().contentResolver,
                            contentURI)

                    // TODO (Step 3 : Saving an image which is selected from GALLERY. And printed the path in logcat.)
                    // START
                    val saveImageToInternalStorage =
                        saveImageToInternalStorage(selectedImageBitmap)
                    Log.i("Saved Image : ", "Path :: $saveImageToInternalStorage")
                    // END
                    binding.btnNpwpCaptureAgain.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                    binding.ivPvNpwp.foreground.clearColorFilter()
                    binding.cvNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
                    binding.btnCaptureNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
                    binding.ivNpwpPreview.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap) // Set the selected image from GALLERY to imageView.
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {

            val thumbnail: Bitmap = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap // Bitmap from camera

            // TODO (Step 4 : Saving an image which is selected from CAMERA. And printed the path in logcat.)
            // START
            val saveImageToInternalStorage =
                saveImageToInternalStorage(thumbnail)
            Log.i("Saved Image : ", "Path :: $saveImageToInternalStorage")
            //binding.btnCaptureKtp.text = getString(R.string.regist_step_2_KTP_retake).toString()
            // END
            binding.btnNpwpCaptureAgain.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            binding.ivPvNpwp.foreground.clearColorFilter()
            binding.btnCaptureNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
            binding.cvNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
            binding.ivNpwpPreview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail) // Set to the imageView.
        }
    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.e("Cancelled", "Cancelled")
    }
    //
}
```

My Problem is why this block is executed, but nothing happend ??

```
 ....
binding.btnNpwpCaptureAgain.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        binding.ivPvNpwp.foreground.clearColorFilter()
        binding.btnCaptureNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
        binding.cvNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
        binding.ivNpwpPreview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail)
......
```

Thank you for respond my question.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with putting another null check for "contentURI". Like :-

```
if(contentURI != null){

        try {
            // Here this is used to get an bitmap from URI
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            val selectedImageBitmap =
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireActivity().contentResolver,
                    contentURI)

            // TODO (Step 3 : Saving an image which is selected from GALLERY. And printed the path in logcat.)
            // START
            val saveImageToInternalStorage =
                saveImageToInternalStorage(selectedImageBitmap)
            Log.i("Saved Image : ", "Path :: $saveImageToInternalStorage")
            // END
            binding.btnNpwpCaptureAgain.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            binding.ivPvNpwp.foreground.clearColorFilter()
            binding.cvNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
            binding.btnCaptureNpwp.visibility=View.GONE
            binding.ivNpwpPreview.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap) // Set the selected image from GALLERY to imageView.
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

As onActivityResult() method is deprecated, its better to use `registerForActivityResult()`. Like below :

```
    private val startForResultToLoadImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            val selectedImage: Uri? = result.data?.data
            if (selectedImage != null){
                 // From Gallery
                 // Use uri to get the image

            }else{
                  // From Camera code goes here.
                  // Get the bitmap directly from camera
                val bitmap: Bitmap = result.data?.extras?.get("data") Bitmap
            }
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            Log.d("log==>>", "Error : ${error.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
}
```

**For gallery call it like:**

```
val intent = Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
```

startForResultToLoadImage.launch(intent)

**For camera call it like:**

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, it)
startForResultToLoadImage.launch(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should:

1. Print log at the start of the function with all of the parameters printed to always know how the code will branch. Something like `Log.i("onActivityResult: ", "requestCode=" + requestCode + “, resultCode=” + resultCode + “, data=” + data);`
2. Check your request code before you check result code since different requests may have different results.
3. You’re assuming the result would be either `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` or `Activity.RESULT_OK` but the result code might be a custom result, so please add another `else` branch after you check `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` to be sure you’re covering all results.
4. Don’t call `Fragment.onActivityResult` from `Activity.onActivityResult` if your activity inherits from `AppCompatActivity`. Activity automatically forward the result to fragments (it even allows request code duplication across fragments without mixing the fragments).

The structure of `onActivityResult` should be mainly:

```java
if (requestCode == REQUEST_1) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_1) {
        // Do your thing
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_2) {
        // Do your thing
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_LAST) {
        // Do your thing
    } else {
        // Important!! Expect the unexpected
    }
} else if (requestCode == REQUEST_2) {
    ...
} else if (requestCode == REQUEST_LAST) {
    ...
}
```

I would use switch-case instead if-else but it’s you code style so I won’t judge :)